# data grid view not working

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, struct

I have developed a form in c# which is called inside a console application.

Below is how i have called the form inside the console.

```
Application.Run(new Form1(display_list));
```

displaylist is a list of struct 
    List  , form_columns is a struct consisting of 3 string values which needs to be displayed side by side in a datagrid.

Below is the constructor of the form

```
public Form1(List<form_columns> disp)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = disp;
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
    }
```

But when the program is run , the datagridview is empty. it is not showing any data .

What mistake am i making?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind the list using BindingList

```
        BindingList<form_columns> bl = new BindingList<form_columns>(disp);
        BindingSource source = new BindingSource(bl, null);   
        //source.DataSource = disp;
```

Comment: I did try the above 3 lines in the code . Now i am getting blank rows and columns in the datagridview. No values in the list was displayed in the grid

Comment: Please check during debugging if the DataSource property actually has any data. Perhaps you pass an empty list to the Form1.